# Reputation point changes because of remove upvote but can't find record

Tags: discussion, reputation-history

Let's say someone upvote my question, and I receive bonus reputation points. Then, that person removed his/her upvote and my reputation gets reduced. My question is in my profile page, I can't find area where I can check an upvote was removed from my question. Is there an option like that on Stack Overflow that I don't know?

Comment: It shows up as "unupvote" in your reputation page.  Looking at your page, I see no evidence of recent vote retractions, only normal downvotes.  It is hard to do for a user, votes get locked-in after 15 minutes and only an edit permits a user to retract it again.